# Reusable function for database access

Tags: react-native, realm

I am currently discovering and learning to dev an app using react native
I don't have a lot of background regarding JS/React etc (more used to C,java, objC,swift etc)

So I am converting a learning app i made in swift in RN. I used the mobile database realm. I have the habit to create a singleton classe to access some method I am using in different places.

here is how I am doing it in RN
I got a js file RealmApi like that

```
let realm = new Realm({
path : "Pleload.realm",
readOnly : true,
schema : [Data, SUBDATA]
});
```

with let say 2 methods I am exporting because I was not able to export the realm var (i did not create a class)

```
module.exports = {
fetchData(){..... return something}
fetchSubData(param){.... return something}
```

}

that I am using like this in a list view

```
    import RealmAPI from './RealmAPI'
    .....
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
           dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(RealmApi.fetchSbuData(this.props.section.code)),
    })
```

It is working, but I got the feeling it is not the good way of doing it.I am style thinking in object way (java etc)

What would be the "correct" way of doing it ? Should I create the realm in each component and duplicating the method ? (that why I am trying to avoid)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to export realm var. The syntax is as below

```
let realm = new Realm({
    path : "Pleload.realm",
    readOnly : true,
    schema : [Data, SUBDATA]
});
export default realm;
```

and use it as below

```
   import MyRealm from '<file path to the above code>
```